# Keyboard shrinks SLDS Modal Size in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, slds

I have a VF Page that displays Contact records and clicking on the contact it opens an `slds modal` in edit modal.

Its works fine in browser but in `Salesforce1` ,as soon as i click an any input form element in the modal, `keyboard pops up and shrinks the size of the modal` and makes the modal body `scrollable`.

Is there any way to fix this?

`ScreenShot`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxfIq.png

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetvar="accounts" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
  <c:RemoteTK ></c:RemoteTK>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121,'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body class="slds" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <ul class="slds-list--vertical">
          <li class="slds-list__item slds-has-divider--top-space" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
              <a href="#" ng-click="openModal(contact)">{{contact.LastName}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-show="showModal">
        <div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
          <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
              <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Edit {{selectedCont.Name}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content">
              <div>
                  <div class="slds-form-element">
                      <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="sample1">Name</label>
                      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                          <input id="sample1" class="slds-input" type="text" ng-model="selectedCont.Name"/>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-form-element">
                      <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="sample1">Account</label>
                      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                          <input id="sample1" class="slds-input" type="text" ng-model="selectedCont.Account.Name"/>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-form-element">
                      <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="sample1">Phone</label>
                      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                          <input id="sample1" class="slds-input" type="text" ng-model="selectedCont.Phone"/>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-form-element">
                      <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="sample1">Email</label>
                      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                          <input id="sample1" class="slds-input" type="text" ng-model="selectedCont.Email"/>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
              <div class="slds-x-small-buttons--horizontal">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" ng-click="closeModal()">Ok</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var force = new remotetk.Client();
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('ctrl',function($scope){
       $scope.contacts = [];
       $scope.selectedCont = "";
       $scope.options = ['Option A','Option B','Option C','Option D','Option E','Option F','Option G'];
       $scope.openModal = function(cont){
           $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal
           $scope.selectedCont = cont;
       };

       $scope.closeModal = function(){
           $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
           $scope.selectedCont = "";
       };

       force.query("Select id,lastname,phone,email,Account.Name,Category__c from contact",function(data){
            $scope.contacts = data.records;
            $scope.$digest();
            console.log(data);
       },function(data){
            console.log(data);
       });

       $scope.update = function(contact){
           $scope.closeModal();
           var contObj = angular.copy(contact);
           delete contObj.$$hashKey;
           delete contObj.attributes;
           delete contObj.Account;
           console.log(contObj);
            force.update('Contact',contObj.Id,contObj,function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
               },function(data){
                    console.log(data);
               });
       }


    });
```

Comment: Can you confirm if this is on Android/ iOS. Please also share your code snippet.

Comment: @GauravKheterpal the issue is on Android and i didn't check it in IOS.I have posted my code.Thank you